# Partial Derivatives and the Multivariate Chain Rule

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

Suppose we have differentiable functions $h: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$, $g: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$ 
h(x,y,z) = (f \circ g)(x,y,z) = f(g_{1}(x,y,z), g_{2}(x,y,z), g_{3}(x,y,z))
$$
where the $g_{i}$ are the components of $g$ in each coordinate direction.

If we use the multivariate chain rule to compute the partial derivative of $h$ w.r.t. $x$, we get 
$$ 
\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}(x,y,z) = \sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{i}}(x,y,z) \cdot \frac{\partial g_{i}}{\partial x} (x,y,z) 
$$
On a theoretical level, I understand what's going on in the chain rule: my question isn't about the chain rule. I know that we're trying to find $Df(g(a)) \circ Dg(a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and we get the result above through a computation with the Jacobians. It's the notation I'm confused about. I have a few questions about this:

1) When we take the partial of $f$ w.r.t. $g_{i}$ above, what does it mean for us to use $g_{i}$ as a coordinate direction? I know that $f$ takes in $g_{i}$ as an argument, but how do you view a function as a coordinate direction?

2)In the expression above, what should the arguments of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{i}}$ be? Should it be $(x,y,z)$ or $(x, g_{2}(x,y,z), g_{3}(x,y,z))$ (supposing $i=1$)?

3) In the case of $i=1$, for instance, is $ \frac{\partial f}{\partial g_{i}}(x,g_{2}(x,y,z),g_{3}(x,y,z)) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(g_{i}(x,y,z), g_{2}(x,y,z), g_{3}(x,y,z))
$?   Because the "regular" chain rule expression requires us to evaluate the partial derivatives of $f$ at $g(x,y,z$).

Comment: You've put your finger on the problem. $\partial f/\partial g_i$ is totally meaningless. If you write $(x,y,z) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)$, that term should be exactly $\partial f/\partial x_i(g(x,y,z))$. This is what happens when people are too addicted to the Leibniz notation for chain rule and don't know what things mean. :(

Comment: @TedShifrin do you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} (g(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}))$?

Comment: No, because you're writing your variables as $(x,y,z)$. I wanted you to think about differentiating the function $f$, before anything else happens, with respect to its three natural variables. To keep the summation notation you used (which I like), I needed to number the variables, just as you numbered the components of $g$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That's what I'm confused about. The coordinate directions of $h$ are $(x,y,z)$, while you're taking those of $f$ as $(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$. How are these two related?

Comment: You can label the variables for $f$ anything you want.  Suppose $f$ were a function of two or four or five variables. You wouldn't want to confuse them with $x,y,z$. So label the variables of f as $u_1,u_2,u_3$, nothing to do with $x,y,z$. Or $x_1,x_2,x_3$. Write out an example where there are different numbers of variables for $g$ and $f$ and you will be less confused.